# Regular expressions match.start() and match.end() example in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Struggling to get a good grasp of *regular expressions* and especially of their `match.start()` and `match.end()` methods.

While playing with this code (found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer)):

```
Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    keywords = {'IF', 'THEN', 'ENDIF', 'FOR', 'NEXT', 'GOSUB', 'RETURN'}
    token_specification = [
        ('NUMBER',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'), # Integer or decimal number
        ('ASSIGN',  r':='),          # Assignment operator
        ('END',     r';'),           # Statement terminator
        ('ID',      r'[A-Za-z]+'),   # Identifiers
        ('OP',      r'[+\-*/]'),     # Arithmetic operators
        ('NEWLINE', r'\n'),          # Line endings
        ('SKIP',    r'[ \t]+'),      # Skip over spaces and tabs
        ('MISMATCH',r'.'),           # Any other character
    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        if kind == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = mo.end()
            line_num += 1
        elif kind == 'SKIP':
            pass
        elif kind == 'MISMATCH':
            raise RuntimeError('%r unexpected on line %d' % (value, line_num))
        else:
            if kind == 'ID' and value in keywords:
                kind = value
            column = mo.start() - line_start
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)

statements = '''
    IF quantity THEN
        total := total + price * quantity;
        tax := price * 0.05;
    ENDIF;
'''

for token in tokenize(statements):
    print(token)
```

I cannot understand the use and logic when computing the line and column using the `mo.end()` and `mo.start()`. **For example**, if I were to have the `NEWLINE` and the `SKIP` to also yield a `Token` output then the column indexes are messed up completely.
Tried re-calculating with the `mo.end()` the column indexes to accommodate for this case as mentioned in the example but failed.
Any ideas, example-code and/or explanations would be awesome.

Comment: If you see at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) there a few examples (although I must say I don't understand much either).

Comment: Thanks, I 've seen them but did not become any wiser in order to implement that example case I mention on the description :/

Comment: I've updated the tokens to match the documentation so that the code you've provided runs correctly: please let me know if that was an intentional omission on your part

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that I believe satisfies your criteria: if you could post what you've tried perhaps we could better understand the problems you're having.

```
import collections
import re
Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    keywords = {'IF', 'THEN', 'ENDIF', 'FOR', 'NEXT', 'GOSUB', 'RETURN'}
    token_specification = [
        ('NUMBER',  r'\d+(\.\d*)?'), # Integer or decimal number
        ('ASSIGN',  r':='),          # Assignment operator
        ('END',     r';'),           # Statement terminator
        ('ID',      r'[A-Za-z]+'),   # Identifiers
        ('OP',      r'[+\-*/]'),     # Arithmetic operators
        ('NEWLINE', r'\n'),          # Line endings
        ('SKIP',    r'[ \t]+'),      # Skip over spaces and tabs
        ('MISMATCH',r'.'),           # Any other character
    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        column = (mo.start() - line_start) + 1

        if kind == 'MISMATCH':
            raise RuntimeError('%r unexpected on line %d' % (value, line_num))
        else:
            if kind == 'ID' and value in keywords:
                kind = value
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)
            if kind == 'NEWLINE':
                line_start = mo.end()
                line_num += 1


statements = '''
    IF quantity THEN 
        total := total + price * quantity;
        tax := price * 0.05;
    ENDIF;
'''

for token in tokenize(statements):
    print(token)
```

Output:

```
Token(typ='NEWLINE', value='\n', line=1, column=1)
Token(typ='SKIP', value='    ', line=2, column=1)
Token(typ='IF', value='IF', line=2, column=5)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=2, column=7)
Token(typ='ID', value='quantity', line=2, column=8)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=2, column=16)
Token(typ='THEN', value='THEN', line=2, column=17)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=2, column=21)
Token(typ='NEWLINE', value='\n', line=2, column=22)
Token(typ='SKIP', value='        ', line=3, column=1)
Token(typ='ID', value='total', line=3, column=9)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=14)
Token(typ='ASSIGN', value=':=', line=3, column=15)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=17)
Token(typ='ID', value='total', line=3, column=18)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=23)
Token(typ='OP', value='+', line=3, column=24)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=25)
Token(typ='ID', value='price', line=3, column=26)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=31)
Token(typ='OP', value='*', line=3, column=32)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=3, column=33)
Token(typ='ID', value='quantity', line=3, column=34)
Token(typ='END', value=';', line=3, column=42)
Token(typ='NEWLINE', value='\n', line=3, column=43)
Token(typ='SKIP', value='        ', line=4, column=1)
Token(typ='ID', value='tax', line=4, column=9)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=4, column=12)
Token(typ='ASSIGN', value=':=', line=4, column=13)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=4, column=15)
Token(typ='ID', value='price', line=4, column=16)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=4, column=21)
Token(typ='OP', value='*', line=4, column=22)
Token(typ='SKIP', value=' ', line=4, column=23)
Token(typ='NUMBER', value='0.05', line=4, column=24)
Token(typ='END', value=';', line=4, column=28)
Token(typ='NEWLINE', value='\n', line=4, column=29)
Token(typ='SKIP', value='    ', line=5, column=1)
Token(typ='ENDIF', value='ENDIF', line=5, column=5)
Token(typ='END', value=';', line=5, column=10)
Token(typ='NEWLINE', value='\n', line=5, column=11)
```

Comment: Why is `column` 1 less than it should be? e.g. first `Token` should have column 1 not 0. Any ideas how can we fix that?

Comment: @Karim because `match.start` uses `0` for the first "column", not `1`.  That's pretty normal in programming.  You can just add 1 when printing it out

Comment: @Karim you'll notice this holds true of the original code as well: it's just not obvious because you never see something printing out at column "0".  But the `IF` is printed at column `4` not column `5` for example

Comment: So right before each `yield` you increase by one the `column`?

Comment: yes just `yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column+1)`

Comment: And one more thing; why is it that `yield` is not only at the very end of the `loop`. This way we will not have two `yield` statements duplicated. Am I wrong in my logic?

Comment: @Karim because in the case of the `yield` for `NEWLINE` you want the yield to happen *before* changing `line_start` and `line_num` so that the `line` index is correct

Comment: @Karim I've updated the code to avoid duplication of the `yield` for `SKIP`

Comment: @Karim actually you're right: the code now only has one `yield`

Answer (score 0):

[`mo.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) and [`mo.end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.end) will return you the start and end indexes of the match so that `string[mo.start():mo.end()]` will return you the matched string. Every time your example matches `\n` it will increase the `line_num` that tracks current line and update `line_start` to contain the index of first character in current line. This allows the program to later calculate the column when token is matched: `column = mo.start() - line_start`.

To illustrate the line and column tracking behavior I've created a simple example that finds all the numbers in given string. For every number it will output the line and starting column:

```
import re

PATTERN = '(?P<NEWLINE>\n)|(?P<NUMBER>\d+)'
s = '''word he12re 5 there
mo912re
another line 17
'''

line = 1
line_start = 0
for mo in re.finditer(PATTERN, s):
    if mo.lastgroup == 'NEWLINE':
        # Found new line, increase line number and change line_start to
        # contain index of first character on the line
        line += 1
        line_start = mo.end()
    elif mo.lastgroup == 'NUMBER':
        # Column: index of start of the match - index of first char on line
        column = mo.start() - line_start
        print('line {0}: {1} at column {2}'.format(line, mo.group(0), column))
```

Output:

```
line 1: 12 at column 7
line 1: 5 at column 12
line 2: 912 at column 2
line 3: 17 at column 13
```